# Comment traduire « me défends » dans la chanson « Conscience » de Merzhin ?

Tags: sens, paroles-de-chanson

Que veut dire « me défends » dans la contexte des [paroles](http://www.parolesmania.com/paroles_merzhin_38544/paroles_conscience_671583.html) ci-dessous (une partie de la chanson *Conscience* de Merzhin) ?

> Conscience, toujours tu me reproches
>   Des choses dont je me défends
>   Cela tout le jour et toute la nuit
>   Je l'entends

Je comprends que le chanteur lutte contre sa propre conscience et qu'il pense qu'elle le lui reproche, mais je ne comprends pas la deuxième ligne. Est-ce que « défendre » ici veut dire « interdire » ou « protéger » ? J'aimerais bien également avoir une explication.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Le sens « protéger » est possible (il s'agit alors de la forme réflexive de la construction « défendre qqun contre qqchose »), mais je soupçonne, étant donné la présence de « reproche », qu'il s'agit du sens de « nier », comme on dirait (exemple tiré de mon Robert) : *il se défend d'être raciste.* C'est alors une forme un peu figée, on se défend contre une *accusation*.